# hide index.php from ajax load search in osclass

Tags: osclass

link look like http://localhost/index.php?page=search&sOrder=dt_pub_date&iOrderType=desc&sPattern=car

// AJAX SEARCH
  $('body#body-search').on('change click', '.link-check-box a, .filter-remove a, form.search-side-form input:not(.term), body#body-search #sub-nav a, #home-cat a, #sub-cat a, form.search-side-form select, .sort-it a, .user-type a,.list-grid a, .paginate a', function(event) {
    var ajaxStop = false;

```
if(ajaxSearch == 1 && event.type != 'change') {
  event.preventDefault();
}


// Disable on mobile devices when input selected from fancybox
if($(event.target).closest('.search-mobile-filter-box').length) {
  if(!$(event.target).closest('#search-sort').length && !$(event.target).closest('.sub-line').length) {     // it may not be required
    var ajaxStop = true;
    //return false;
  }
}

var sidebarReload = true;

if($(this).closest('.sidebar-hooks').length || $(event.target).attr('name') == 'locUpdate') {
  sidebarReload = false;
}

var sidebar = $('.filter form.search-side-form');
var ajaxSearchUrl = '';

if (event.type == 'click') {
  if(typeof $(this).attr('href') !== typeof undefined && $(this).attr('href') !== false) {
    ajaxSearchUrl = $(this).attr('href');
  }
} else if (event.type == 'change') {
 ajaxSearchUrl = baseDir + "index.php?" + sidebar.find(':input[value!=""]').serialize();
}


if(ajaxSearch == 1 && $('input[name="ajaxRun"]').val() != "1" && (ajaxSearchUrl != '#' && ajaxSearchUrl != '') && !ajaxStop) {
  if(ajaxSearchUrl == $(location).attr('href')) {
    return false;
  }

  sidebar.find('.init-search').addClass('btn-loading').addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', true);
  sidebar.find('input[name="ajaxRun"]').val("1");
  $('#search-items').addClass('loading');


  $.ajax({
    url: ajaxSearchUrl,
    type: "GET",
    success: function(response){
      var length = response.length;

      var data = $(response).contents().find('#main').html();
      var bread = $(response).contents().find('ul.breadcrumb');
      var filter = $(response).contents().find('.filter').html();

      sidebar.find('.init-search').removeClass('btn-loading').removeClass('disabled').attr('disabled', false);
      sidebar.find('input[name="ajaxRun"]').val("");

      $('#main').fadeOut(0, function(){ 
        $('#main').html(data).show(0);

        $('#search-items').hide(0);
        $('#search-items').removeClass('loading');
        $('#search-items').show(0).css('opacity', 0).css('margin-top', '50px').css('margin-bottom', '-50px').animate( { opacity: 1, marginTop:'0', marginBottom:'0'} , 300);

      });

      if(sidebarReload) {
        $('.filter').html(filter);
      }

      $('ul.breadcrumb').html(bread);
```